# Unable to get GaalVM to work on latest version of OS/X?

Tags: java, macos, javafx, gluon

I have tried loading the latest versions of GraalVm from the site onto OS/X from : graalvm-ce-java11-darwin-amd64-20.2.0.tar.gz

I tar this bundle, following the instructions and sudo mv the directory to /Libaray/Java/JavaVirtualMachines and setup the .bash_profile per the instructions.  If I run the java_home -V command I see the VM there.

When I try to execute any of the command line utilizes from the VM (java, javac, jar, etc.) I get a fault by OS/X saying the application is from an untrusted developer.  I then I have to to control panel/security and settings/general and manually select each an every binary and each and every native library one at a time and tell OS/X to add them as an exception to allow them to be run.

Am I missing something or is this expected behavior?  Is there a better way to install the graalVM on OS/X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old issue but maybe it helps:
https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/1724
I wonder why this has not been fixed yet.